# Display the incremented size of ArrayList

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, output

I have a method that extract emails from the web. I would like to display the emails size in a dialog while the method is executed. I tried this code:

```
<p:commandButton id="extractbutton" value="Extract" 
   actionListener="#{mailMB.searchEmails()}" 
   onstart="blockUIWidget1.show();" 
   update="tableemails, :confirmPurchase, :confirmPurchaseTest, :mainform"
   oncomplete=" blockUIWidget1.hide(); if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) freeMails();" />

<p:dialog widgetVar="blockUIWidget1" modal="true" closable="false">  
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">                      
        <p:graphicImage url="pictures/loading_bar.gif" />
        <h:outputText value="Please wait..." />  
        <h:outputText value="#{mailMB.mails.size()}" />
    </h:panelGrid>  
</p:dialog>
```

However, 0 is always displayed until the method completed.
How can I display the mails `size()` incrementally?

Comment: `onstart` might be too early for the `blockUIWidget1` to get the current value from the backing bean. What's the scope of your backing bean and how are you updating the value?

Comment: @kolossus My backing bean is sessionScoped. How should i update the size of my mails ArrayList???

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't load new informations from mailMB.mails : 
You request somethink like the server side to refresh mails, but you don't use new data in your pop'up. Maybe can you try to get the response and load it in your popup before display it.

I hope it can help you.